# Get items from SPO and past them in Azure SQL

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, azure, sql, logic-app

I am trying to make a logic app with "Recurrence" triger which get items from SPO list (from view) with condition:

- if have null values, then pass them some string or boolean (if column is boolean type)

Then get rows from Azure SQL table and compare with data from SPO (above), if there is a match then skip them, if is not a match then add row in Azure SQL with values from SPO item.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should look at the [SharePoint List Webhook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/lists/overview-sharepoint-list-webhooks)

if I read the docs correctly allows you to setup an Azure function or Webjob that triggers on SharePoint List Webhook event corresponding to ListItem changes

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, job is done ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Work is done ! With Execute a SQL query (V2) I am getting values from dtb. and with expression from condition `length(string(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_2')?['resultsets']))` I now if item which I want to add is already in database.
With another Execute a SQL query (V2) I can add specific values.